# Get access token using only email/refresh_token with C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have a table in a database with emails and their refresh tokens of multiple Hotmail/Outlook.com accounts (nothing else).

I'm trying to create an Access Token using the Refresh Token but I can't find any code using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` or `Microsoft.Graph` libraries to perform that action.

Here is the partial code in a console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /* other code */
    string email, refreshToken; // obtained from database
    TokenCache tokenCache = new TokenCache(); // how do i "fill" this object?

    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        "appId",
        "redirectUri",
        new ClientCredential("appSecret"),
        tokenCache,
        null);

    IAccount account = cca
        .GetAccountsAsync()
        .Result
        .FirstOrDefault();

    AuthenticationResult result = cca
        .AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[] { "scopes" }, account)
        .Result;

    GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/",
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }));

    var msgs = client
        .Me
        .MailFolders
        .Inbox
        .Messages
        .Request()
        .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From })
        .Top(10)
        .GetAsync();

    /* more stuff to do */
}
```

I have been able to do this using PHP but now I need it to do it in .net

**UPDATE: I will show the complete code using the answer of Marc LaFleur**

```
ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    appId,
    redirectUri,
    new ClientCredential(appSecret),
    new TokenCache(),
    null);
AuthenticationResult result = (cca as IByRefreshToken).
    AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(scopes, refreshToken).Result;

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
    "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/",
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
));

var msgs = client.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().
    OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC").
    Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From }).
    Top(10).
    GetAsync().Result;
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have, exactly?

Comment: @Zer0 I don't known how to serialize the refresh token in the tokenCache object (see comment in line 5) so i can get the access token with it (see cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync in line 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.ibyrefreshtoken.acquiretokenbyrefreshtokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) using Microsoft.Identity.Client -Version 3.0.2-preview:

```
ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
    appId,
    redirectUri,
    new ClientCredential(appSecret),
    new TokenCache(),
    null);

AuthenticationResult result = (cca as IByRefreshToken).
    AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(scopes, refreshToken)
   .Result;
```

Comment: I added the line after cca declaration and got "MsalServiceException: AADSTS70002: The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter." I checked the cca object if the ClientCredential is correct and got: Assertion=0 Audience=0 Certificate=0 ContainsX5C=false Secret="appSecret" ValidTo=0. Something else that I forgot to add in my code?

Comment: Interesting, updating my example with an alternative method. It looks like something [changed in 3.x](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-2.x-to-MSAL.NET-3.x#acquire-token-by-refresh-token).

Comment: There is no AcquireTokenByRefreshToken and no ExecuteAsync with it. But I wrote these lines ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<AuthenticationResult> awaiter = ccaRt.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(scopes, refreshToken).ConfigureAwait(false); AuthenticationResult result = awaiter.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); tried false and true but still got the same error in both cases.

Comment: What version of MSAL are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.Identity.Client 2.7.1 downloaded using NuGET; last update Feb 21, 2019

Comment: Ah, that's it. Try using `3.0.2-preview` instead of `2.7.1`: `Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Version 3.0.2-preview`

Comment: I did what you told me. It worked (even using the previous code you wrote) but... for some reason the access token can't be used when I do the Request of the messages (error CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A)

Comment: Forget it! I got it! I have to change a parameter at the moment of creating the GraphServiceClient object adding the baseUrl!